# Media player on Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, media-player

I am doing a simple application on Android studio that plays a song. I managed to make a song play when I get to the specific activity. My question is- when I go out of my app(I leave it working in the background) and go back into it, or when I rotate the phone, the song starts playing from the begging. How do I make the song keep on playing from the place it stopped when I went out of my app/ how do I make the song keep on playing when I rotate the phone?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#mpandservices

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into MVVM design pattern as live data is life-cycle independent, What is happening is common. When you rotate your screen or go out and back into the app, the activity cycle is being affected. Your activity literally restarts thus restarting your song.

Here are a few links that may help you on your way. Best of luck.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

https://blog.mindorks.com/mvvm-architecture-android-tutorial-for-beginners-step-by-step-guide